# Adding attributes to a link to an uploaded file

Tags: 8, theming

I have been asked to add target="_blank" to the links that are produced when a user uploads a file on a Drupal 8 site.

The field type is "File". Multiple uploads are allowed.

Twig debug shows me that the field is being produced by the core template "file-link.html.twig". The entire uncommented contents of that template are:

```
<span{{ attributes }}>{{ link }}</span>
{% if file_size %}
  {# @todo remove class before Drupal 9.0.0 #}
  <span class="file-size">({{ file_size }})</span>
{% endif %}
```

I brought that template into my custom theme and tried to add the attribute to the link. I thought I'd be editing the {{ link }} part of the template, changing it to attach attributes. I did variations of this:

{{ link(item.title, item.url, attributes.setAttribute('target','_blank')) }}

Every syntax I tried produced a fatal PHP error. Thinking I was doing the attribute syntax wrong, I tested  by simply trying to add a single class.

```
{{ link(item.title, item.url, { 'class': ['bananas'] }) }}
```

That was still a white screen of death, so I guess I can't use that syntax on the {{ link }} field in my file-link template.

I've been googling my eyeballs out of my head. I found this [cool idea](https://gist.github.com/lauriii/15a1305ed57c7fe629ca13c1663db193):

```
{% for item in items %}
  {{ item.content|merge({'#attributes': {'class': ['button', 'button--arrow', 'button--centered']}}) }}
{% endfor %}
```

so I adapted it for my field.html.twig template like so, changing this part:

```
{% for item in items %}
    <div{{ item.attributes }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

to this:

```
{% for item in items %}
      <div{{ item.attributes }}>{{ item.content|merge({'#attributes': {'target': ['_blank']}}) }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

And while at least the page loaded and didn't have a fatal error, the target attribute did not appear on the link.

Does anyone have any advice for me getting an attribute onto a file upload link? Almost everything I've found has to do with the link field, not the file upload field. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**file-link.html.twig**

```
<span{{ attributes }}>{{ link|merge({'#attributes': {'target': '_blank'}}) }}</span>
{% if file_size %}
  {# @todo remove class before Drupal 9.0.0 #}
  <span class="file-size">({{ file_size }})</span>
{% endif %}
```

---

Alternatively, you can also solve this via preprocess.

**mytheme.theme**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_file_link(&$variables) {
  $variables['link']['#url']->setOption('attributes', ['target' => '_blank']);
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. I tested both methods and either one works. Thank you and if I could give two checks I would! 

For you and anyone who is interested in this topic, which of these two methods do you prefer? My pure guess only surface logic: the twig version is slightly more efficient because it only gets run if the template is used to build the page, whereas the preprocessing is run on every page build. I don't believe it makes a human noticeable difference, but I have to pick one, so trying to use logic.

Comment: FWIW, I'm going with the preprocess method for now, since it means I have one less custom template. But if I was already using that custom template for something else, I think I would use that method instead.

Comment: To me it would come down to. Do I want to give a front-end developer, which I don't expect to know PHP, the ability to potentially accidentally, or on purpose, be able to remove the open in a new tab feature? If the answer is yes, template file. If the answer is no, this should never be removed, preprocess.